# How to make Github API call with token?

Tags: swift, github

I want to make api call which lists all the followers of certain user.
I was testing it and I realized that there are limit amount of api call that can be made by one IP.
Github document says that if I make api call with personal token, the limit number will increase but I don't know how to make api call with token.
[image]

Let's say my token is bbbb and User is aaaa, then how should I form URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an API call to `github` with a personal token to retrieve the list of all `your` followers, try this approach, as shown in the example code (with a valid token of course).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var followers: [UserFollower] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List(followers) { follower in
            Text(follower.login)
        }
        .task {
            await getFollowers()
        }
    }
    
    func getFollowers() async {
        let token = "YOUR-TOKEN"  // <--- here
        if let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/user/followers") {
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.setValue("application/vnd.github.v3+json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            do {
                let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
                followers = try JSONDecoder().decode([UserFollower].self, from: data)
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct UserFollower: Identifiable, Codable {
    let login: String
    let id: Int
    let nodeID: String
    let avatarURL: String
    let gravatarID: String
    let url, htmlURL, followersURL: String
    let followingURL, gistsURL, starredURL: String
    let subscriptionsURL, organizationsURL, reposURL: String
    let eventsURL: String
    let receivedEventsURL: String
    let type: String
    let siteAdmin: Bool
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case login, id, url, type
        case nodeID = "node_id"
        case avatarURL = "avatar_url"
        case gravatarID = "gravatar_id"
        case htmlURL = "html_url"
        case followersURL = "followers_url"
        case followingURL = "following_url"
        case gistsURL = "gists_url"
        case starredURL = "starred_url"
        case subscriptionsURL = "subscriptions_url"
        case organizationsURL = "organizations_url"
        case reposURL = "repos_url"
        case eventsURL = "events_url"
        case receivedEventsURL = "received_events_url"
        case siteAdmin = "site_admin"
    }
}
```